# iOS - creating symlinks... is that safe?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an app that is localized in several languages, leading to a lot of resources in duplicate. I have created symlinks using unix "ln -s" command, linking repeating files, so I can get rid of file redundancy.

Is that safe to use symlinks in that case?

I have tested in the simulator and on my device and it works.

Will the links be followed in the customer device?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having odd problems with Xcode failing to build if I included symlinks in the app. Perhaps this issue is fixed with Xcode 4.5 (I submitted a bug report to Apple a while back).

By the fact you've been able to build it, it must now be fixed. 
It's possible however that the built IPA file will have multiple copies of the files though. It's worth unzipping the built file and checking to see if there are multiple copies.

Linking to the same file in Xcode may be a better option if it turns out there are multiple copies.

Comment: it is working fine... yes, you are right, Xcode is following the links and duplicating the files. linking in Xcode???? how?

Comment: I mean right-clicking on a group or folder in the project explorer (say your spanish resources folder), and selecting a file from your shared resources folder with 'copy to group' unticked. You can do this from multiple groups in your app and they'll all link to the same actual file on disk.

Comment: the problem is that when you localize files, lets say images, Xcode move them to .lproj directories, one for each language, duplicating, triplicating, etc. the file.